# How to view POP mail in a web browser

Tags: email, webmail

I have an email account with my hosting package. Is there a web service that will allow me to view my emails from any web browser (to simulate a Gmail like experience). So far I only know how to do it via the Mac Mail app and my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use gmail and add your hosting email account as a POP3 account: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287

Comment: The other answers I'm sure were good, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [mail2web.com](http://mail2web.com/)

> mail2web.com offers a variety of
>   services, including our flagship
>   mail2web Webmail service which
>   provides secure and anonymous access
>   to your POP or IMAP email accounts
>   from any browser or hand-held device.
>   With mail2web Webmail you can pick up
>   your email from any internet enabled
>   device from anywhere in the world.

Comment: Good but I won't give you a +1 on top of the one you have, because you pathetically just quoted their marketting blurb.    Anyhow, yes it is a good site i've used it many times, been around a while, I put it to good use a number of times 10 years ago.. and no doubt it's still going strong.

Comment: Thus the quote. ;)

Comment: There is no way to export emails with web2mail and I could not make pop3 to work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a webmail client to your webserver.  Here are some clients you can look at:  http://www.noupe.com/ajax/10-ajax-webmail-clients.html

Comment: Which clients does the link talk about? Why not put them in your answer?

Comment: Giving the asker a bunch of names he wouldn't recognize didn't seem the best way to answer.  The link takes you to a page that gives a screen shot of each client's look and gives a small description.  The main point was that he could install his own webclient.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It is impossible to view POP3 in a web browser.
POP3 protocol was created to allow a mail client to download mails from a POP3 server and then the POP3 client will have option to delete the mails. Therefore, it is impossible to read the mail over and over again, if it is deleted. Even if you do not delete it, you have to redownload all the mail and that wastes time.

Comment: Did you read the other answers